# Amazon App Store Authorship

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

Uploaded an application to Amazon App store. I noticed under authorship it just says Developer.

Is Amazon selective about what developers get an author page or will this be updated later?

---

[image]

---

Comment: Used the contact forum on the dev site and they very quickly fixed this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that field is determined by what you wrote in the "Developer or Company" field during your profile creation. I don't think you can change it after the fact, you may need to create a new profile if you want to change it.

Comment: Thanks, I think that is pretty lame on Amazon's part. I was hoping there would be a link where the user could see my other apps.